# Generic JSON parsing in Android

Tags: java, android, json, parsing, jackson

I have a JSON

```
 {
    "info": {
        "info1": {
            "age": "30",
            "city": "New york"
        },
        "info2": {
            "sleeping": "false"
        },
        "info3": {
            "shopping": "false",
            "eating": "Buger"
        }
    },
    "data": [{
        "name": "XYZ",
        "email": "xyz@123.com"
    }, {
        "name": "ABC",
        "email": "ABC@123.com"
    }]
}
```

I need to make a parser that would be generic, and extract names for objects, arrays and individual key pair text.
I will be generating a query using these values.
Only "info" and "data" tags will be fixed rest all can change. We can have empty "info" or different children like "info1", "info2".... "info5" ...
Similarly, individual "info" child can have multiple children like "info1" can have 2 entries or 4 entries.

I tried using jackson library, but not able to traverse the complete json.

**UPDATE**: using jackson 2.7.2 (latest)
Used following code

```
    JsonFactory factory = new JsonFactory();

    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper(factory);
    JsonNode rootNode = mapper.readTree(jsonString);

    Iterator<Map.Entry<String, JsonNode>> fieldsIterator = rootNode.fields();
    while (fieldsIterator.hasNext()) {

        Map.Entry<String, JsonNode> field = fieldsIterator.next();
        System.out.println("Key: " + field.getKey() + "\tValue:" + field.getValue());
    }
```

It iterated for the "info" and "data" key. Need to iterate over complete json.

Comment: But jackson can do that perfectly well for you. Have you tried using a `JsonNode`?

Comment: I am new to Jackson :(

Comment: https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.2.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/JsonNode.html#get(java.lang.String) check java doc of Jackson

Comment: And what version of Jackson are you using? Have you tried and read the javadoc of ObjectMapper, in particular the readTree*() methods? Those return a JsonNode.

Comment: please check my update. using same and latest version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`JsonNode` can be used to parse whole jsonObject. `JsonNode` get method can be used to traverse the given JSON.

e.g. :

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
JsonNode rootNode = mapper.readTree(data);

JsonNode infoNode = rootNode.get("info");

Iterator<Map.Entry<String, JsonNode>> infoFieldsIterator = infoNode.fields();
while (infoFieldsIterator.hasNext()) {

    Map.Entry<String, JsonNode> field = infoFieldsIterator.next();
    System.out.println("Key: " + field.getKey() + "\tValue:" + field.getValue());
}

JsonNode dataNode = rootNode.get("data");

for (int i = 0; i < dataNode.size(); i++) {
    JsonNode dataNodeNum = dataNode.get(i);
    Iterator<Map.Entry<String, JsonNode>> dataFieldsIterator = dataNodeNum.fields();
    while (dataFieldsIterator.hasNext()) {
        Map.Entry<String, JsonNode> field = dataFieldsIterator.next();
        System.out.println("Key: " + field.getKey() + "\tValue:" + field.getValue());
    }
}
```

For more info please [check here](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.2.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/JsonNode.html).

Comment: As explained in question, I will be not aware of any KEYS in the json except "info" and "data", they could be empty as well.

Comment: In that case, you can first get info and data nodes and then iterate those elements accordingly. See my updated answer.

Comment: Updated iterator for data and infoNode

Comment: Jackson has JSON Pointer support, too

Comment: added another loop to drill down to third layer

Answer (score -1):

Why not try GSON.

https://github.com/google/gson

You can use models inside models to achieve what you need.

ALL you need to do is serialise data using gson as follows

```
         @SerializedName("info")
           private infomodel info;
```

you can create a seperate model called info model which contains serialized name for its objects.

use the below code to get object from json

```
        Gson gson=new Gson();
        Model yourModel=gson.fromJson(<your json object as string>);
```

Comment: Jackson also does serialization. Please try to address the needs of the question rather than redirect elsewhere.